# Can I add more bounty to a question which already have bounty offered by another user?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I want to offer bounty to a question and the question already have a bounty. Can I add additional bounty for the question? Also the question is not asked by myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> Can I raise my bounty?
>
> You can offer as many bounties on a question as you want. However, only one bounty can be active on a question at a time. Moreover, any user may have at most 3 concurrent bounties at a time.

---

> Can I add additional bounty for the question?

As in adding to the total? No.

Comment: That's disappointing. It could be a group effort - 4 people giving 50 reputation as a bounty instead of 1 person giving 200 reputation makes giving bounties more desirable.

Comment: True but nothing stops you to post it as an idea for improving SE ;) @mochan