# Can we kill the "bounty" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Yesterday a [question about Ask Ubuntu was asked](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5959/can-i-add-more-bounty-to-a-question-which-already-have-bounty-offered-by-another) (by a user with more than 300 rep) on the main site.   It was eventually migrated, but the tag the OP created ([bounty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bounty)) is still around.

Can a moderator please kill this tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've deleted the old question, so the tag should just naturally die. I know this has been mentioned a few times before, but for clarity (and posterity) moderators can't just kill tags. That's something we need to ask the Stack Exchange team to do for us, if a bad tag gets out of hand. Otherwise a tag with no questions will eventually die off. So long as it doesn't become an abused tag it'll just disappear.

Comment: Ah, OK, I didn't know that.  I thought all tags had to be killed manually.