# Kill `parallel-port` tag with fire

Tags: discussion, tags

The title is pretty descriptive: can we kill the [parallel-port](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/parallel-port) tag with fire?

Only 2 questions are affected by this tag, and LTP is a dead technology, pretty much it can be absorbed by the hardware tag. Opinions?

Questions affected:

- [How to set up a parallel port printer in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307913/how-to-set-up-a-parallel-port-printer-in-12-04)
- [How can I get an USB to LPT adapter to work? (12.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258924/how-can-i-get-an-usb-to-lpt-adapter-to-work-12-04)

Comment: I've untagged those two questions, so even if we don't explicitly kill it it should get autopruned.

Comment: Hmm... What should we do with this? The tag now has no questions so we could either have @Jorge post an answer or we could dupe it to this perhaps: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5973/can-we-kill-the-bounty-tag

Comment: I tried to edit the tag to kill it, but got rejected for both question, so I decided open a meta question so we can reach concensus.

Comment: @Braiam The tag isn't on those questions, if there are other questions with the tag then the tag won't die.  Otherwise, it'll gracefully die out on its own and automatically disappear after a while.  So this doesn't need any real discussion, the tag will disappear itself.

Comment: @ThomasW. Did you read the first comment by Jorge? He removed the tag already ;)

Comment: @Seth yes I did, however I believe Braiam might have missed that, or didn't acknowledge it so I restated that, namely since they said "So we can reach consensus" on this issue, which isn't really needed here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our dear friend Jorge Castro already removed the glaring tag:

- *How to set up a parallel port printer in 12.04?* revisions: https://askubuntu.com/posts/307913/revisions
- *How can I get an USB to LPT adapter to work? (12.04)* revisions: https://askubuntu.com/posts/258924/revisions